# Confusion about definition of locally compact topological space

Tags: general-topology

I was reading van Dantzig's theorem from Terry Tao's notes, where I encountered that he's writing locally compact topological space to mean every point has a *compact* neighborhood.

What does locally compact mean? Every point having compact neighborhood or every point having neighborhood whose closure is compact?

If anyone explains in detail it would be great.

Comment: They are equivalent in Hausdorff spaces. Ordinarily one refers to points having compact neighbourhoods as locally compact. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space

Comment: Does you working definition of "neighborhood" require that it be an open set?  (There are two standards here.)

Comment: Is your confusion based on whether neighbourhoods are by definition open, or is it based on the distinction of "every point has a (quasi)compact neighbourhood" vs. "every point has a (quasi)compact _closed_ neighbourhood"?

Answer (score 2):

$X$ is a topological space throughout.

There are two standard definitions of a [neighborhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)).  Both are used widely.  The difference you are highlighting comes down to whether neighborhoods are defined to **contain** an open subset, or defined to **be** an open subset.

- For $x \in X$, $V \subset X$ is a neighborhood(1) of $x$ if $x \in U \subset V$ for some open set $U \subset X$.  (note 1)
- For $x \in X$, $V \subset X$ is a neighborhood(2) of $x$ if $x \in V$ and $V$ is open.  (note 2)

In the familiar setting $X = \mathbb{R}$, there are no neighborhood(2)s that are compact.  However, for each $x \in X$, there *are* neighborhood(2)s, $V_x  = (x-1/2, x+1/2)$, for instance, whose closure is closed and bounded, hence compact (by the [Heine-Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem)).  In this setting, the closures of the neighborhood(2)s are neighborhood(1)s, so we get these two characterizations:

- $\mathbb{R}$ is locally compact because every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ has a compact neighborhood(1).
- $\mathbb{R}$ is locally compact because every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ has a neighborhood(2) whose closure is compact.

(note 1):  See, for instance, Bredon, Glen E., *Topology and Geometry*, [ISBN ISBN 0-387-97926-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387979263), p. 4: "If $X$ is a topological space and $x \in X$ then a set $N$ is called a *neighborhood* of $x$ in $X$ if there is an open set $U \subset N$ with $x \in U$."

(note 2):  See, for instance, Munkres, James R., *Topology: A First Course*, [ISBN 0-13-925495-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0139254951), p. 96: "Mathematicians often use some special terminology here.  They shorten the statement '$U$ is an open set containing $x$' to the phrase '$U$ is a **neighborhood** of $x$.'"  This language also appears in the second edition of this work, [ISBN  978-0131816299](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131816292), still p. 96.  Alternatively, Kelley, John L., *General Topology*, [ISBN 0-387-90125-6](http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~olegviro/topoman/part1.pdf), p. 14: "A *neighborhood* of a point is any open set containing this point."  Kelley then asserts that analysts and Bourbaki use "neighborhood" in the neighborhood(1) sense.

Comment: Isn't there a FAQ containing this information?

Comment: Can you please provide an example of a standard Topology textbook in which, by definition, all neighborhoods are open sets?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos : Done.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos : And done adding a reference for neighborhood(1) which seems much harder to do from standard Topology textbooks.

Comment: I think the OP's problem is with a different issue. In a space where every point has a quasicompact neighbourhood [in the sense (1) of course], it need not be the case that every point has a closed quasicompact neighbourhood. Consider the line with infinitely many origins. Every origin has quasicompact neighbourhoods, but no closed quasicompact neighbourhood.

Comment: @DanielFischer : I'm not convinced commenting here will draw a clarification from OP.  Perhaps you should apply this comment to the Question, or firm it up into an Answer.

Comment: Hello Eric. I'm reading Introduction to Topology by Gamelin and Greene and there they use the definition neighborhoods(1). Is this consistent with the second definition of local compactness you gave, i.e. $\mathbb R$ is locally compact because every $x\in\mathbb R$ has a neighborhood whose closure is compact? Can we speak of one definition being more general than the other?

Comment: @psie : That implication requires some additional ingredient (for a general topological space).  See Daniel Fischer's comment for an example.